# How to set currentIndex of SwipeView to currentIndex of TabBar "by reference" after going to specific page?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm getting started with QtQuick Controls 2.0. I have experience with C++ and a small amount of experience with Qt, but I have not worked with QML before.

I have a `TabBar` and a `SwipeView` that are linked to each other. What I mean by this is that when you select a page on the `TabBar`, the `SwipeView` goes to that page. When you swipe to a page from the `SwipeView`, the `TabBar` updates itself to reflect that.

As a learning exercise, I decided to create a button that would send the user to the second page. The issue is that I can't seem to find a way to do so without messing up the link between the `TabBar` and the `SwipeView`.

The following code is the best I've come up with. It correctly goes to the second page, and when I change the current page with the `TabBar` the `SwipeView` still updates. However, *swiping* to a new page no longer updates the `TabBar`. It appears that setting `tabBar.currentIndex` to `swipeView.currentIndex` only has the effect of setting by reference when done with the colon to initialize. Doing so with an equals sign sets by value. How can I move to a specific page while still maintaining the invariant that `swipeView.currentIndex == tabBar.currentIndex`?

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page {
            Button {
                text: qsTr("Continue to Page 2")
                onClicked: {
                    tabBar.currentIndex = 1;
                    // this next line merely sets tabBar.currentIndex to 1
                    tabBar.currentIndex = swipeView.currentIndex
                }
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                width: text.implicitWidth
                height: text.implicitHeight
            }
        }

        Page {
            Label {
                text: qsTr("Second page")
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("First")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr( "Second")
        }
    }
}
```

The C++ code  is simply the default that Qt Creator provided for me:

```
// main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to move to the next or the previous page without breaking the `currentIndex` bindings, you can call [`incrementCurrentIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-container.html#incrementCurrentIndex-method) or [`decrementCurrentIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-container.html#decrementCurrentIndex-method), respectively. These methods were introduced in Qt Quick Controls 2.1 in Qt 5.8.

Given that the `currentIndex` setter aka. `QQuickContainer::setCurrentIndex()` is a slot, you can also call `setCurrentIndex()` from QML to jump to an arbitrary page. This will not break the existing bindings either.

```
Button {
    onClicked: tabBar.setCurrentIndex(1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In the case of wanting to go to page 20, for example, would it be preferable to simply use a for loop and some math based off of `currentIndex` to get to the right page, or would it be better to do it as I did in my answer?

Comment: Jumping to an arbitrary page requires a more complicated solution, indeed. It can be two-way signal handlers, or utilize `Qt.binding()` to restore bindings. This discussion makes me realize that we could simply allow calling `setCurrentIndex()` from QML.

Comment: It turns out that `setCurrentIndex()` is actually a slot, so you can already call it from QML without breaking the bindings. We'll add this to the documentation to make it official.

Comment: That was the simple solution I was looking for! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could be looking for [Signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html). From the Qt documentation:

> ## Property Change Signal Handlers
>
> A signal is automatically emitted when the value of a QML property
>   changes. This type of signal is a property change signal and signal
>   handlers for these signals are written in the form *on<Property>Changed*
>   where *<Property>* is the name of the property, with the first letter
>   capitalized.

Thus, for your example:

```
SwipeView {
    id: swipeView
    ...
    currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex
    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        tabBar.currentIndex = currentIndex
    }
...
footer: TabBar {
    id: tabBar
    currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex
    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        swipeView.currentIndex = currentIndex
    }
    ...
```

And that way you can simply set the currentIndex of either and rest assured that they will remain "linked" due to the signal handlers.

### Edit:

[As pointed out by jpnurmi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43578012/how-to-set-currentindex-of-swipeview-to-currentindex-of-tabbar-by-reference-af#comment74281645_43579913), you can also use `Qt.binding` like so:

```
onClicked: {
    swipeView.currentIndex = 1;
    swipeView.currentIndex = Qt.binding(function() {return tabBar.currentIndex})
}
```

This will restore the binding after the static value has been assigned.